# How to get function name (function declaration) from VC++ .dll file?

Tags: visual-c++

Can anybody tell me how can i get the function declaration i mean function name from VC++ DLL file.

I have .dll of VC++ and i want to extract function name from it ?
Is it possible then let me know.

Thanks in Advance

Thanks,
Neel

Comment: Has the dll been built with debug info?

Comment: No DLL has not been build with debug info.

Answer (score 0):

Since the DLL is not built with debug info, you can only look at functions that are exported by the DLL.  Use "Dependency Walker" to see which functions are exported by the DLL.  You will see 2 types of functions.

If the name of the function is not mangled (like all functions in the Windows DLL's) you're out of luck.  There is (as far as I know) no way to get the arguments of these functions (except looking in the documentation or in include files that might be delivered with the DLL).

If the name of the function is mangled, it will have a name like this: ?makeSizePositive@?$RectangleTemplate@J@TOOLS@@QAEXXZ.  This method was originally named makeSizePositive, and all the gibberish added to it give some clue about the class where the method is located, the namespace, and the arguments.  See http://www.kegel.com/mangle.html#operators about an explanation.

Comment: any ways that i can see the only function name without argument that is used by functions ?

Comment: I don't think so.  You can either see the mangled function name with an indication about all arguments (including if there are no arguments at all), or the unmangled function name without any information.